# Custom directive with watcher only fires once. Does not watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm attempting to fire an animation using a custom directive, "activate" which I use as an attribute here, partials/test.html

```
<div activate="{{cardTapped}}" >
```

I define the directive following my app definition in js/app.js

```
myApp.directive('activate', function ($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.activate,function(newValue){
      console.log('fire');
      if(newValue){
        $animate.addClass(element, "full");
      }
      else{
        $animate.removeClass(element, "full");
      }
    },true);
  };
});
```

However, $watch is only firing on page load. When `cardTapped` changes values, nothing registers. I've tried several variations of parameters here to no avail and I've seen a dozen questions similar to this but so far I havent found a solution

Any thoughts?

Comment: try `attrs.$observe`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote it like this: `activate="{{cardTapped}}"` while it should be `activate="cardTapped"`.

When you want to use a watcher, let it watch a variable, not a string.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfabbkf3/)

Comment: What if you're trying to watch an attribute for changes? This is not the solution... I want it to be a string, and watch the attribute, not a variable.